# How to extract/match file type extension from array of extension types in powershell

Tags: arrays, powershell

I want to extract only required file types from Sharepoint libraries using Powershell

I'm using the below logic but it is not working 100% correctly. It still matches the filename contains extension type which is not good.

Please help me correct the script.

```
$libfiles = ".pptx",".xlsx",".xls",".docx",".doc",".pdf",".jpeg",".jpg",".ppt",".xlsm",".gif",".png"
$libfilesregex = [string]::Join('|', $libfiles)
$arr = @("xlsfile.avi","asxlsxfile.mdf","navigation.css")
foreach($i in $arr)
{
    if($i -match $libfilesregex)
    {
        Write-Host " $($i) File type exists "
    }
    else
    {
        Write-Host " $($i) File type does not exist "
    }
}
```

It's outputting:

> xlsfile.avi File type does not exist
>
> asxlsxfile.mdf File type exists
>
> navigation.css File type does not exist

Note how none should be reported as existing, but `asxlsxfile.mdf` unexpectedly is.

Thanks
Vishwa

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$libfiles = "(\.pptx)$","(\.xlsx)$","(\.xls)$","(\.docx)$","(\.doc)$","(\.pdf)$","(\.jpeg)$","(\.jpg)$","(\.ppt)$","(\.xlsm)$","(\.gif)$","(\.png)$"
$libfilesregex = [string]::Join('|', $libfiles)
$arr = @("xlsfile.avi","asxlsxfile.mdf","navigation.css")
foreach($i in $arr)
{
    if($i -match $libfilesregex)
    {
        Write-Host " $($i) File type exists "
    }
    else
    {
        Write-Host " $($i) File type does not exist "
    }
}
```

Note that I simply 'escaped' the period (`.`) in front of all of your extensions listed.  This is by no means the most efficient method, but helps to simply show you how the `.` represents "anything" in RegEx terms, as opposed to actually representing the period itself.  If you want to define an explicit period, you escape the normal representation by using a backslash `\`.

This gives you:

> xlsfile.avi File type does not exist
>   asxlsxfile.mdf File type does not exist
>   navigation.css File type does not exist

And to test positive results, for validation, and changing the `$arr`:

`$arr = @("xlsfile.pptx","pptxlsmgif.mdf","navigation.doc")`

Yields:

> xlsfile.pptx File type exists
>   asxlsxfile.mdf File type does not exist
>   navigation.doc File type exists

EDIT: Thanks to the (much better, and efficient) answer below, I've updated the `$libfiles` to show an edge case issue where filenames such as `docx.xls.ddf` would **also** erroneously report as correct when they should not.  So, I've anchored to the "end" of the filename, using `$` to the end of each extension, and encapsulated in parentheses as well.

Answer (score 6):

I believe this is what you are looking for.  I explicitly extract the file extension from the file array and print if the extension exists.

```
$libfiles = ".pptx",".xlsx",".xls",".docx",".doc",".pdf",".jpeg",".jpg",".ppt",".xlsm",".gif",".png"
$arr = @("xlsfile.avi","asxlsxfile.mdf","navigation.css", "lib.pptx")
foreach($i in $arr)
{
    if($libfiles -contains [io.path]::GetExtension($i))
    {
        Write-Host  "$([io.path]::GetExtension($i)) File type exists "
    }
    else
    {
        Write-Host "$([io.path]::GetExtension($i)) File type does not exist "
    }
}
```

Comment: ++ for a pragmatic approach that _bypasses_ the regex problem. I suggest you make your code more PowerShell-like in two respects: use the `-contains` operator instead of the `.Contains()` method,
and remove the unnecessary `$(…)` wrapper around the `[io.path]::GetExtension()` call: `if ($libfiles -contains [io.path]::GetExtension($i)) { …`

Comment: Thank you for the constructive feedback on my post.  In the future I will be sure to adjust my code accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

To make your regex (regular expression) work as intended, two things are needed:

- You must ***escape* regex metacharacters** (characters with special meaning, such `.`) in the strings to look for; `\` is used for escaping, so a *literal* `.` must be represented as `\.`

  - While you could hard-code the escaping into the components of your regex, that is cumbersome and not always an option. Luckily the .NET framework offers `[regex]::Escape()` for generic escaping of arbitrary strings.
- You must ***anchor* the regex to the *end* of the input string** with `$`, given that that you're matching filename extensions and that the **`-match` operator performs *substring* matching by default**.

<sup>The reason for your false positive was the absence of these two aspects, causing substring `sxlsx` of input filename `asxlsxfile.mdf` to match subexpression `.xlsx`</sup>

The following command does just that:

```
$libfilesregex = '(' + (($libfiles | % { [regex]::Escape($_) }) -join '|') + ')$'
```

`$libfilesregex` now contains this:

```
(\.pptx|\.xlsx|\.xls|\.docx|\.doc|\.pdf|\.jpeg|\.jpg|\.ppt|\.xlsm|\.gif|\.png)$
```

which produces the desired result.

Comment: I love this.  Concatenation along with regex integration.  Very nice.